# Regarding function returning pointer

Tags: c++

I want to clarify something about function returning pointer.

I understand pointer concept but in case of returning from function it is confusing me.

I learnt that when we want to return some data from function we write the type of data in return type for example in case of returning int type of data the return type will be int.

so when we want to return an address of some variable from a function we write return data type to be of some pointer type because memory address point to some sort of memory location that's why the return type is of pointer type what I want to clarify is that now this means that data type of addresses in c++ is of pointer type

Comment: `int` for a plain integer value. `int*` for pointers to integer value(s). Just like normal.

Comment: Oh and remember that you can't return pointers to local variables, as their life-time ends with the function returning.

Comment: What you say above seems correct, it's hard to know what it is that you want clarifying. But while returning a pointer to a local variable is legal but it is almost certainly a bug for the reason mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: I think it might help if you share some code to clarify what do you mean.

Comment: You can return pointers to *static* variables of the function, though.

Answer (score 1):

This how a general factory function works:

```
class HobNob;
...
HobNob* CreateHobNob()
{
    return new HobNob();
}
...
HobNob* myHobNob = CreateHobNob();
```

of course in real life we'd never use bare pointers, but the general idea is we need pointers because we don't want to be passing around `HobNob`s (which may be huge) but handles (pointers) to one created on the heap. We can now also fully control its lifecycle.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but can you explain it in some simple words

Comment: `HobNob` is just a made up name for this example. It can be replaced with anything: `Car`, `Cat`, `Array` *etc*.

Comment: I understand now

Comment: *'in real life we'd never use bare pointers'* – depends... as function parameters, they *can* be appropriate (see e. g. Herb Sutter's [GotW 91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)). Admitted, in *given* example, return type *would* be a `std::unique_ptr`...

Comment: @Aconcagua OP is beginning to understand what a pointer is, don't throw GotW at them at this stage.  Stick to the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns a pointer looks something like this:

```
int* foo()
{
    // some code
    return intPointer; // assuming intPointer is of type int*
}
```

or

```
int* foo()
{
    // some code
    return new int; // return a newly created integer
}
```

If your function is supposed to create a new object of a type and return it.

or

```
int* foo()
{
    int* arr = new int[10]; // create an array dynamically
    // some code
    return arr; // return an array
}
```

If your function is supposed to return some array.

Obviously, you can change `int`with any data type you want.

Also, as someone else pointed out it is not good idea to return the address of a local variable to outside of the function, so you would have to define the local variable as a static variable if you want to do that, otherwise it's undefined behaviour.